# What's the soultion of this? WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "X264enc"

Tags: gstreamer, video-conversion

[![Screenshot of WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "X264enc"][1]][1]

I have checked similar questions and found to install
gst-plugins-ugly-1.0. But not able to find any packages on linux. Can I expect any answers?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is spelled `x264enc` and *not* `X264enc`. Case matters.

Comment: ok..Thanks..but got different issue ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error

Comment: Are you sure the .mp4 file contains an mpeg4 video? You may want to use an auto-plugger like `decodebin` instead. `.. ! qtdemux ! decodebin ! x264enc ! ..`

Comment: Yes..It contains and also auto-pluggers are fine for me now.